# Killing a process with python in the Travis CI environment

Tags: python, travis-ci, python-unittest

So I have a test that runs a background process and stops it at the end of the test but I'm having some trouble with it stopping when it runs in Travis. It goes a little something like this,

```
import unittest
import subprocess, os, signal

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        # tactic: look for the background command using the shell ps command
        # and kill that process using os.kill (running on Debian)
        process1 = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        process2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'python manage.py my_background_process'], stdin=process1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        # my_background_process is a custom django command, I don't think that is relevant though
        process1.stdout.close()
        output = process2.communicate()[0] # output from the grep command
        for line in output.split('\n'):
            if line != '' and 'grep' not in line: # ignore the grep command and non-existent process
                pid = int(line.strip().split(' ')[0]) # pid in the first part of the string
                os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)

    def test_one(self):
        subprocess.Popen(['python', 'manage.py', 'my_background_process'])

    def test_two(self):
        subprocess.Popen(['python', 'manage.py', 'my_background_process'])
```

Where the custom django command here is very simple, e.g. `my_background_process.py`

```
import time

while True:
    f = open('test_file.txt', 'wb')
    f.close()
```

This all works on my local machine which is running Mac OSX but when I push the code up to my github repository which triggers a Travis CI build it fails because the background process isn't stopped and starts conflicting with other test. After some debugging, it appears the `output` variable is just an empty string, i.e. the code can't find the background process. So perhaps my real question is how to list the processes in Travis?

Apologies I've just written most the code out here, with a bit of copy and paste to demonstrate the issue, so there may be typos or other things I missed out, I will try and set up a reproducible error but hopefully there is enough information here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

By keeping a reference to the `Popen` object I can kill the process through python without having to access the os.

```
import unittest
import subprocess, os, signal

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        self.bg_process.kill()

    def test_one(self):
        self.bg_process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'manage.py', 'my_background_process'])

    def test_two(self):
        self.bg_process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'manage.py', 'my_background_process'])
```